# Algorithm complexity means worst case complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

We have best case, average case and worst case time complexities. So someone asks us about the complexity of an algorithm what is he referring to?

Comment: We need more context. Otherwise it could be any of them.

Comment: As quasiverse says, it could be any of them.  So if someone asks, give him all of 'em.  Problem solved :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Colloquially:** Usually, average case.  This is why people say that Quicksort is O(N log N) time and a hash table lookup is O(K) time (K = key size).  They are worst case O(N^2) and O(K*N), respectively.  I recommend being explicit.

**Academically:** Usually, worst case.  However, in academia people are usually interested in proving the complexity class for a given problem, rather than examining the complexity of an algorithm.  For academicians, an algorithm might just be a handy proof for an upper bound on complexity rather than the actual object of study.

The other gotcha is that "average case" is entirely dependent on the input distribution.  Most people assume uniform distributions, unless they use the phrase "real world" at which point it's anybody's guess what their input is.

Comment: Li & Vitanyi in "An Introduction to Kolmogorov Complexity and its Applications" section 4.4 show that "the average-case computational complexity of any algorithm whatsoever under the universal distribution turns out to be of the same order of magnitude as the worst-case complexity". Roughly speaking, if your input is generated by a randomly chosen computer program, there is a worryingly large chance that this program will happen to generate a lot of worst-case inputs.

Comment: Of course, one must specify the distribution when generating a "randomly chosen computer program" or else such an analysis is impossible.

Comment: The "universal distribution" specified above comes with a precise definition, although it is pretty robust to changes affecting only details. You can see the full argument by googling for the phrase within double quotes above, or going to http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/1991/1991A.pdf. FWIW, I suspect that there may be a loophole for randomised algorithms running off a source of true random numbers.